# Firebase - How to write using curl?

Tags: json, curl, firebase

I run sample code on firebase rest api tutorial. It says that

> Data from our Firebase database can be read by issuing an HTTP GET request to an endpoint:

```
 curl 'https://samplechat.firebaseio-demo.com/users/jack/name.json'
```

> A successful request will be indicated by a 200 OK HTTP status code.
>   The response will contain the data being retrieved:

`{ "first": "Jack", "last": "Sparrow"` }

My result is here :

[image]

Now I try to write to firebase database using below command

```
curl -X PUT -d '{ "last": "sparrow"}' https://samplechat.firebaseio-demo.com/users/jack/name.json
```

The result is : 
[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please not post images. Copy and paste the terminal output into your question.

Comment: can you please share your hierarchy of `users`?

Comment: I copied and pasted your command. It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Please try:

```
curl -X PUT -d "{\"name\":{\"last\": \"sparrow\"}}" https://samplechat.firebaseio-demo.com/users/jack.json
```

This works for me on windows.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried following:

```
curl -X PUT -d '{"name":{ "last": "sparrow"}}' https://samplechat.firebaseio-demo.com/users/jack.json
```

If that works you can handle "first" too.

Comment: you must be doing some other mistake, that can be only identified when you expose your complete flow

Comment: I install curl , and try to run these commands. Is there any steps for adding an object to firebase db?

Comment: thanks for vote up :) and why you guys are using curl, why don't you use postman like thing or write simple code that adds data to firebase

Comment: I follow this guide https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/setup.html. It uses curl on command line.